# NHibernate ISession.Replicate with SQLite and native id generation

Tags: unit-testing, nhibernate, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

We are mapping the primary key of an object like this:

```
Id(x => x.Id, "ID").GeneratedBy.Native("SEQUENCENAME");
```

We have business logic depending on certain ids to exist (legacy, not easily changed). New objects should get generated ids from an Oracle sequence, but there are always rows with known ids.

We're using SQLite for unit testing and I need to persist new objects to the in-memory database with these known ids. This will not work with any of the following methods:

```
session.Replicate(objectWithKnownId, <any replication mode>);
session.Merge(objectWithKnownId)
```

According to nHibernate documentation, the `Replicate` method seems to be what I'm looking for.

> Persist all reachable transient
>   objects, reusing the current
>   identifier values.

When using it with SQLite, however, I will only get generated ids. Can anyone think of a good way of solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this problem and reading the respons from AlexCuse (+1 to his answer), I deemed it was not possible to use the native id generator in this case. I both needed unit tests to work when saving rows with known ids in test setups and tests inserting with autogenerated ids.

One option was to have some sort of check in the fluent mapping that would use `GeneratedBy.Native("SEQUENCENAME")` in production code and `GeneratedBy.Assigned` in tests, but I didn't like the idea of having differences related to NHibernate mappings between unit tests and production.

What I opted for in the end was to handle this in the repository. I have an `Add` method in the relevant repository and this will handle assigning a generated id from a sequence if the id isn't already set, something like this:

```
public void Add(TheClass newObject) {
    if (newObject.Id == 0) {
       newObject.Id = sequenceGenerator.GetNextValue("SEQUENCENAME");
    }
    session.Save(newObject);
}
```

In unit tests I will insert a mock sequence generator in the repository. You could argue that this is similar to the approach of having different mappings for unit tests and production code, but I think this approach makes the difference a bit more isolated. The most important reason, though, is that it allows me to use both assigned and automatically generated ids also in unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

I typically run any database tests against the database that I'm running the app against - SQLite can be good for quick tests but it is just missing too many of the features that you'll find in a full blown DBMS. You may be able to use a method like the one discussed [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/krzysztof_kozmic/archive/2009/08/17/adjusting-nhibernate-mapping-for-tests.aspx) to tweak your mappings at runtime if it is a mapping issue.

You could also preload a SQLite database with the entities you need, and copy this in for reuse every time you run the test.  This is probably the route I would take for something like this, but I can't offer any technical details on how to do it.

To be honest it sounds a bit strange to have your business logic depend on certain Id's - I would think you'd want it to depend on certain *entities* - you could then insert these entities and store their generated Id's for the duration of your tests.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I agree that it might seem a bit odd to have logic depend on certain Id's, but this is a legacy database where I can't change this.

Comment: That makes sense, sounds painful though!  I think using the preloaded DB is going to be your best bet.  Good luck :)